# What determines the rate at which I recover stamina?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

During my trip through the tutorial dungeon, I noticed my stamina seemed to recover more slowly with the more weight my character carried. Since I plan on specializing in two-handed weapons, it's important for me to understand what factors increase or decrease stamina regeneration so I can prevent myself from running out of stamina at crucial moments in epic battles. What other factors affect the rate at which I recover stamina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the weight thing. I tested it and I didn't notice any difference. I can't guarantee it though, maybe it has something to do with armor worn, perks etc.

What I can tell you is that there are the following ways of recovering stamina, apart from letting stamina restore over time:

- Drink stamina potions
- Choosing the "Respite" perk in the Restoration tree will make it so healing spells also recover stamina
- Some types of food restore stamina.
- Stamina is fully restored on level up.
- Sleeping and waiting fully restores stamina (regardless of the length)

This is mostly from http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Restoration.

Also, as a neat bonus: When you sprint, don't let stamina drain completely, since it will take a couple of seconds before it starts recharging again. If you sprint until you have just a little bit of stamina left, the stamina will start recharging immediately.

source: http://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/m9wfo/tip_when_sprinting_dont_let_stamina_completely/

Comment: There are also enchantments that increase stamina regeneration speed.